# Why does this ability have its mana cost written twice?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Korozda Monitor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKorozda%20Monitor%5d) reads:

> Scavenge {5}{G}{G} *({5}{G}{G}, Exile this card from your graveyard: Put a number of +1/+1 counters equal to this card's power on target creature. Scavenge only as a sorcery.)*

I would like to know why the 5(G)(G) is listed twice, outside of the parentheses and inside. I've seen this format on other cards too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's written like that because that's what the ability means; "Scavenge [cost]" means "[Cost], Exile this card from your graveyard: Put a number of +1/+1 counters equal to this card's power on target creature. Scavenge only as a sorcery.". The italic text in parentheses is called *reminder text*, and it's there in this case to tell you what scavenge does.

Comment: Note that reminder text is not the actual definition of the term; that's in the comprehensive rules. In this case they're essentially the same, though, just a more explicit, correct phrasing in the full rules.

Comment: Ahhh there we go! Very well explained, thank you. The redundancy was confusing, but this makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Jefromi I'll work on my formatting, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

"Scavenge {5}{G}{G}" is a keyword ability. A keyword ability is a shortcut that represents one or more other abilities. The parenthesized, italicized text is a reminder of the gist of the ability for which the keyword stands.

Specifically, the keyword ability "Scavenge [cost]" means "[Cost], Exile this card from your graveyard: Put a number of +1/+1 counters equal to this card's power on target creature. Scavenge only as a sorcery.".